# Capacitors charging, resistance much more?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, electrical-resistance, capacitance, short-circuits

I am overwhelmed by the amount of doubts i am having regarding this device
(CORRECT ME WHEREVER I AM WRONG PLEASE)

1. First things first if we connect a capacitor using two ideal wires (for each plate) and a cell the cell drags electrons out of the metal of one plate and sends it to another (accumulates) plate. This creates the equal opposite charge on the plates
   why is it necessary for a resistor to be connected in series with the capacitor for charging?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer to Chittaranjan rout's second question.

Yes indeed, you will form a capacitor exactly as you have described it, and at the instant you connect the wires to a cell, a very tiny burst of current will flow out along the wires and charge them up very quickly.

Because the size of the wires is small, the *capacitance* of a parallel pair of wires with an insulator between them will be very very tiny- but *not negligible*, as follows:

The higher the frequency, the lower the impedance of any capacitor will become. at *radio frequencies*, the capacitance of a pair of closely-spaced wires becomes significant and can in fact completely upset the radio circuit containing them.

For this reason, great care must be taken in designing the physical layout of components and traces on a board designed for radio frequency applications, to ensure that these *stray capacitances* will not stop the circuit from operating properly.

Comment: Thank you very much
all 3 of you cleared it!
also can this tiny burst of electricity make really small bulbs glow

Comment: no, the current burst will probably be way too small to light a bulb.

Answer (score 2):

There will be a transfer of electrons to the empty capacitor. If there is no resistance, the current will be infinite which is not good (and not possible).
$$ I = \frac{dq}{dt} = C\frac{dV}{dt} $$
also

$$ I = \frac{V}{R} $$ so if $R = 0 $, you can see the problem.

Comment: sir thank you very much. But when short circuit happens current still flows even if R=0

Answer (score 2):

As @Bahrudin Trbalic already pointed out, if there were zero resistance the initial current to an uncharged ideal capacitor when switched on to a voltage source would be theoretically be infinite. Fact is, however, there is always resistance in the circuit (with the exception of a superconductor).

As a practical matter, in designing equipment one always needs to make sure there is sufficient resistance in a capacitive circuit to prevent very high charging/discharging currents. Years ago, back in the lab testing electronic equipment under fault conditions involving shorting resistors, we would occasionally experience an exploding capacitor due to high current.

> If two copper wires connected to a cell are simply kept at a close
> distance with a di electric between them. Simply we can say that no
> current will flow as circuit is not closed. But cannot we think of it
> as a capacitor with copper plates and it is charged and so current
> flows? pls sir I am confused.

You misunderstand how current flows to and from a capacitor. The following is intended to give you a feel for what is going on, without the mathematics.

The current does not flow *through* the dielectric. It is charge that is moved by the voltage source, say a battery, from one plate of the capacitor around to the other plate without the charge actually passing through the dielectric.

Think of the positive terminal of the battery as attracting (pulling) electrons from one plate making that plate more positive and the negative terminal depositing (pushing) the electrons onto the other plate making it more negative. In the beginning it is easy for the battery to do this (do work) which is why the movement of charge per unit time (current) is initially high, limited only be the resistance in the circuit.

But as the positively charged plate becomes more positive it becomes harder and harder for the positive battery terminal to pull electrons from it (due to their attraction) and harder and harder to push the electrons onto the negatively charged plate (due to repulsion). Thats why the current goes down as the capacitor gets more charged. Eventually, the voltage on the capacitor becomes equal to the battery, so the current stops.

All during the charging (or discharging) process the current is limited by the resistance in the circuit path of the movement of the charge. This is not the resistance of the dielectric but the resistance in the path around the dielectric, i.e., the resistance of your copper wires.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you 
Now please clarify me regarding the following:-
If two copper wires connected to a cell are simply kept at a close distance with a di electric between them. Simply we can say that no current will flow as circuit is not closed. But cannot we think of it as a capacitor with copper plates and it is charged and so current flows?
pls sir I am confused.

Comment: @chittaranjanrout, see my answer below. -Niels

Comment: @chittaranjanrout I have update my answer to address your follow up questions.

Comment: Thanks Bob D. But I am not able to understand if charges are circulated to charge the capacitor even if the circuit is opened, then if connect a bulb in between the two then that charge charging the capacitor must pass through the bulb and glow it. It means we have circulation of charges or CURRENT itself with a open circuit.
please sir